# GIT: Should I commit output files (like *.exe, *.lib) when project in a stable revision?

Tags: git

Version 1.0 of my project builds in Visual Studio 2008 successfully, But when I upgrade Visual Studio to version 2010, building my project failed (for some reasons).

My project changed and new release is ready (Version 2.0). It builds on Visual Studio 2010 successfully.

Now, if I want to access "my-project-version-1.0.exe", I should checkout version 1.0, install Visual Studio 2008 and build it by Visual Studio 2008. I can't build it by Visual Studio 2010.

I didn't commit any output files of my project.

Should I commit output files (like *.exe, *.lib) when project in a stable revision to access older versions of my project in next times?

Is there any better idea?

Comment: See also http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/128238/is-it-good-practice-to-store-framework-runtimes-under-source-control for a more general context.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Putting non-source files under version control is generally not a good idea. If you insist, you can add it in one commit, and remove it in the next one, and tag that commit.

What you can do however, is to keep the executables separately. For example if you use github, you can upload files so that you can download them later, for example already compiled executables or libraries.

Comment: If the binaries are large, even if they are removed they will remain in the history making the repository larger.

Comment: @johnny, well if only 1 instance of them remain in the repository it's not a big deal. Indeed, he wants to keep the binaries somewhere, so the space needs to get wasted anyway.

Answer (score 3):

You should have continuous integration set up so when you have a stable version there will always be an artifact published (executables, documentation etc) for it.

For more info look for [**jenkins**](http://jenkins-ci.org/).

Just a note: the repository is just for source code and all the other files that can be used to generate the executables. ***You should generally avoid putting executables in the repository.***

Answer (score 2):

The best idea would be to make it work in Visual Studio 2010.

I personally, and in all professional contexts I work in, prefer to keep compiled files out of the repository. Binary diff just doesn't make sense.

Instead keep a backup of all versions outside the repository (or in another repo), so your source code is kept cleanly separated from your compiled files.

Answer (score -1):

We put binaries under version control. They are in a separate directory from the code, and we have our cmake scripts copy the binaries to/from the directories they are output to.

The /src/ directory has an external link to /bin/, so anyone checking out /src/ automatically gets the binaries. The cmake scripts then copy the binaries from /src/bin/ to /build/debug or /build/release (for Visual Studio). After compilation, the updated binaries are copied back to /src/bin/

I can make a change in something low-level, compile, commit, and when a coworker updates, they don't have to recompile my code when they are working on something several layers up.